# She fell off her bike three times this week vs She has fallen off her bike three times this week

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

The book I'm studying gives as the correct answer the following sentence :

> She fell off her bike three times this week.

Is present perfect simple incorrect in this case? (She has fallen over three times this week)

Comment: No, it would not be incorrect (I think I would be more likely to use it!).

Answer (score 1):

As usual, with the choice of perfect or not, they are both perfectly good, and can refer to *exactly* the same circumstances.

The only difference is in whether the speaker is choosing to present the multiple events of falling off the bike as a completed event, or as having relevance to the present. Both are possible, meaningful, and sensible.

As examples (only examples) of why you might choose one or the other: if you are going to talk about her intention to carry on riding, you might choose the perfect, as you are thinking about the sequence of events continuing through the present.

If you are thinking about some action you are going to take in connection with the falling off the bike, you might choose either.

If this is a self-contained statement, and you are going to talk about something else, you might choose the simple past - but you might not, even then.